# NullReferenceException when accessing an array of Rectangle Shapes

Tags: c#, .net, sfml, sfml.net

I'm struggling to understand why accessing an object in this array throws a NullReferenceException.
I initialized the array right beforehand, so what's trying to be referenced should exist.
parent.rowlength and parent.collength are the size of an array initialized earlier in code, and i know they return the right values.
I'm pretty much out of ideas here.
Edit: I should clarify, this happens on the first iteration of the for loops.
[image: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.']

Here's the code in the picture, let me know if you need to see more.

```
        RectangleShape[,] cells = new RectangleShape[parent.rowLength, parent.colLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.rowLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < parent.colLength; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + j);
                cells[i, j].Size = new Vector2f(10, 10);
                cells[i, j].Origin = new Vector2f(0, 0);
                cells[i, j].Position = new Vector2f(i * 10, j * 10);
                cells[i, j].FillColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `cells[i, j]` is null... you need to `cells[i, j] = new RectangleShape();` after `Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + j);`

Comment: @Chetan ahh I see, thank you. I'm kinda new to this and would have assumed it wasn't null because of the already existing `= new RectangleShape[parent.rowLength, parent.colLength];`

Comment: `new RectangleShape[` is an array.. .not a single object.. an array is used for storing multiple objects of the same types.. but it does not created objects in them... the objects needs to be created explicitly.

Comment: @MachCoyote essentially you told the program to give you 10 buckets. But you never said what to put *into* those buckets. Then you said, get me the content of bucket number 2 and the program essentially said: "There is nothing in there, mate!"

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to inspect `cells`.